# Bind a List data to repeater control

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

[image: My Repeater]
What i want to do is i want to bind the response that i`m getting to the repeater control.
In the response there are fields for Name, Question, Disclaimer etc. I want to bind these field data to the controls in the repeater.

What i`m doing is :

```
 protected void rptCustInfo_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
            {
                Label headertext = new Label();
                headertext = e.Item.FindControl("lblHeaderText") as Label;
                //headertext.Text = custInfo.CustomizationName;
                Label questiontext = new Label();
                questiontext = e.Item.FindControl("lblQuestionText") as Label;
                //questiontext.Text = custInfo.QuestionText;
                //headertext.Text = "";
                //headertext.Text = 
            }
        }
```

This is how my response is created:

```
public List<CustomizationListCustomization> GetPackageCustomization(string PackageCode)
    {
        List<CustomizationListCustomization> arrCusts = SiteConfiguration.customizationList.Customization.Where(cust => cust.PackageList.Contains(PackageCode)).ToList();

        return arrCusts;
    }
```

But I cannot find any result. any suggestions how can i achieve this ?
[image: My ObjecT Response]

Comment: Why do you need the ItemDataBound event? I don't see any special thing that you're doing in that event aside from setting their value? You should just bind them like <asp:Label ID=lblHeaderText runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CustomizationName")' />

Comment: Also, you can bind the options like <asp:RadioButtonList Name="rdbtnOption" runat="server" DataSource="custInfo.OptionList" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" />. Note: Replace the textfield and valuefield with the correct property name from your CustomizationListCustomizationOption class.

Comment: ^ I am doing the same as you said but it gives me error

Comment: Can you provide the error?

Comment: Sorry I does t not provide any error but it displays nothing on the page.

Comment: Are you setting the datasource of your repeater control? (e.g. rptCustInfo.DataSource = GetPackageCustomization; rptCustInfo.Databind();)

Comment: yes.. I have.
  rptCustInfo.DataSource = custInfo.GetPackageCustomization(VisitorSession.PackageCode);
                    rptCustInfo.DataBind();

Comment: You should step into your code and see if your data has records or something is going on.

Comment: My repeater datasource gets filled and i can see this by stepping into the code. what actually i want to do is, i want to get the list of data and bind the individual data into the designated controls that exists in the repeater control. for example labelHeading will contain the customizationName value and as so, the labelQuestion will contain QuestionText value.

Comment: Can you paste your actual repeater code instead of the screenshot so that I can just copy and paste for my answer?

Comment: Well, i have posted it already in question. the design view and also the itemdatabound event is it.

Comment: Yes but it's an image file (screenshot) and there's no way to copy the text. You will have to manually retype everything if I or someone wants to post an answer. So, if you need help... you need to help us also ;-)

Comment: @AbidAli ***What is the output are you expecting? Could you draw in Paint or MS word, and upload the screenshot? Could you also post CustomizationListCustomization class?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 protected void rptCustInfo_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomizationListCustomization custItem = e.Item.DataItem as CustomizationListCustomization;
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            if (custItem != null)
            {
                Label headertext = e.Item.FindControl("lblHeaderText") as Label;
                Label questiontext = e.Item.FindControl("lblQuestionText") as Label;
                Label lblFooter = e.Item.FindControl("lblDisclaimerText") as Label;
                RadioButtonList rdbOptions = e.Item.FindControl("rdbtnOption") as RadioButtonList;

                headertext.Text = custItem.CustomizationName;
                questiontext.Text = custItem.QuestionText;
                lblFooter.Text = custItem.CustomizationDisclaimer;
                ListItem radiolistitem = null;

                if (rdbOptions != null)
                {
                    foreach (var ip in custItem.OptionList)
                    {
                        radiolistitem = new ListItem();
                        radiolistitem.Text = ip.OptionText + " " + ip.OptionPrice.ToString("c");
                        radiolistitem.Value = ip.OptionText;
                        rdbOptions.Items.Add(radiolistitem);
                    }
                }

                //radiolistitem.Attributes.AddAttributes(ip.OptionXML) = custItem.OptionList.Where(p => p.OptionXML != null);

            }
        }
    }
```